# unattended-upgrade does not update security updates

Tags: unattended-upgrades

I run unattended-upgrade with Allowed-Origins set to security and nothing listed in the blacklist. However when I run unattended-upgrade -d, the log lists a blacklist with all my security updates listed. No packages are updated. What could I be doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I too suffer from this, unfortunate that nobody has answered. 11 out of my 12 servers fail to do updates.

Comment: On my Debian system it was because I was still running squeeze (oldstable) instead of wheezy (stable).

Therefore, in the `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-ugprades` I had to change         `"${distro_id} stable";` to `"${distro_id} oldstable";`.

But I don't know if this can be applied to Ubuntu.

Comment: Could you add the configuration file of unattended-upgrades? The default is to do nothing.

Comment: unlikely, he has never been seen again since Nov 13 :-)

Answer (score 0):

OK what I did and it worked.

1. when the update appears unclick the Ubuntu base upgrade leave every
   thing else.
2. it should give you an error like its a dependent upgrade.
3. then go to the Ubuntu softwarecenter "this is what fixes it" it shouldn’t work it asked if you want it fixed say yes. 
   4.then rerun the Ubuntu upgrade this time clicking the Ubuntu base on so its clicked.
4. and you are done takes about 5 mins.